# How can I find the success or failure status of a Dymos/OpenMDAO problem in a way that is accessible to a script?

Tags: python, optimization, openmdao

I have a Dymos problem set up and am running it (optimising and simulating) in a loop, varying certain input parameters

I have a script that calls on Dymos to optimise & simulate many times. When I need to call Dymos once, I generally check the opt report to see its success/failure status. However, after calling many optimisations, the reports are all in the same folder with very similar non-descriptive names, as seen below.

[image]

I'm not sure how easy it is to specify save names that would be ore descriptive for me. Even if I could, having a script analyse an html file to get a success/failure boolean isn't ideal. Is there another more convenient place this information can be found? I was thinking maybe in the case recorder (.db) files?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71575802/run-driver-run-problem-converged-feedback